# Smoothing property of the Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It is well known that the heat diffusion equation

$$ u_t - u_{xx} = 0  ,\quad u(0, x ) = f(x) , $$

has the smoothing property.

The question is, how about the imaginary equivalent of it, namely the Schrodinger equation?

$$ i u_t = u_{xx} ,\quad u(0, x ) = f(x) .  $$

If the initial state $f$ is not derivative at some point, is this property retained by the solution $u$?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281145/connection-between-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-and-heat-equation

Comment: sometimes it seems, since $f(x)=\delta(x)$ corresponds to the fundamental solution, which is analytic